# Change lexing rule with Python's PLY library

Tags: python, lexical-analysis, ply

In my compiler class, our lecturer told us that the grammar for the language we will implement will require lookahead in the parser.  With a tool like flex, that can be easily done with `foo/x`.

I am currently trying to do an example program in Python with the PLY library to see if Python would be a good fit for the project.  I'm trying to implement a simple version of FORTRAN's do loop:

```
-- Spaces are ignored in FORTRAN
DO 5 I=1,10   -- Loop
DO 5 I=1.10   -- Assignment (DO5I = 1.10)
```

Currently, my idea is to match the `DO` keyword, look ahead to see if the rest of the input matches a loop.  If it does, return the `DO` token.  Otherwise, I'd like to "rewind" the input and go into the identifier rule.  Something like:

```
def t_do(t):
    'do'
    if re.match(do_loop_regex, t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.lexpos:]):
        return t
    else:
        t.rewind() # this is what I need to figure out
        return t_identifier(t)

def t_identifier(t):
    '[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*'
    return t
```

Comment: Why are you trying to analyze the grammar with lex instead of yacc ?

Comment: You need to determine in the lexing phase whether `DO 5 I` is an identifier or the keyword `DO` followed by the label `5` and the identifier `I`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with Ply, but requires some data massaging and token building.

```
import re
from ply import lex

tokens = ('LOOP','ASSIGNMENT')
literals = '=,'

re_float = r'(\d+\.\d+)'
re_int = r'(\d+)'
re_ident = r'([A-Za-z]\w*)'
re_expr = '(%s)' % '|'.join([re_float, re_int, re_ident])

re_loop = 'DO%s%s=%s,%s' % (re_int, re_ident, re_expr, re_expr)
@lex.TOKEN(re_loop)
def t_LOOP(t):
    return t

re_assignment = '%s=%s' % (re_ident, re_expr)
@lex.TOKEN(re_assignment)
def t_ASSIGNMENT(t):
    return t

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lineno += len(t.value)    # count newlines

def t_error(t):
    print "syntax error at %s, line# %d" % (t.value, t.lineno)

DATA = """-- Spaces are ignored in FORTRAN
DO 5 I=1,10   -- Loop
DO 5 I=1.10   -- Assignment (DO5I = 1.10)"""

def preprocess(data):
    re_spaces=re.compile('\s*')
    re_comment=re.compile('--.*$')
    lines = []
    for line in data.split('\n'):       # split into lines
        line = re_spaces.sub('', line)
        line = re_comment.sub('', line)
        if not line: continue           # skip blank lines
        line = line.upper()
        lines.append(line)
    return '\n'.join(lines)+'\n'

print re_assignment
lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input(preprocess(DATA))
while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok: break
    print tok
```

First, you have to manually strip comments, spaces, and force to uppercase.  Then you build a parser which basically implements your grammar inline.  I think it would eventually become unmanageable.  If it were me, I think it would be much easier to implement my own lexer which just does line-by-line regular expression matching.  All Ply's lexer really does is build one huge regular expression with all your little regular expressions and then progressively matches tokens.